# RstDocument in kivy Accordion is blocking all interaction

Tags: python, kivy, accordion, kivy-language

I want to create an Accordion containing content consisting of an RstDocument and a button. The Accordion shall be scrollable as well as the content of the RstDocument when this content is larger than the given space. So I came up with the following code but after some clicks on AccordionItems all further interaction is blocking. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.rst import RstDocument
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ShowrstApp (App):

    def update_size(self, instance, *args):
        instance.size = 60 * len(instance.children)

    def build (self):
        numitems = 10

        root = BoxLayout()
        accheight = numitems * 60
        accitems = Accordion(id='acc_panel', orientation='vertical', pos_hint={'top': 1}, size_hint_y=None,
                            height=accheight, md_bg_color=(1, 1, 1, 1))

        for i in xrange(numitems):
            item = AccordionItem(title='This is item: %d' % i)
            somecontent = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
            somecontent.add_widget(RstDocument(text='Some nicely formatted text here'))
            somecontent.add_widget(Button(text='click here', height=(42), size_hint=(1,None)))
            item.add_widget(somecontent)
            item.bind(children=self.update_size)
            accitems.add_widget(item)
        sv = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False)
        sv.add_widget(accitems)

        root.add_widget(sv)
        return root

Window.size = (350,650)
showrst = ShowrstApp()
showrst.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the scrolling effect works when the RstDocument Boxlayout is either horizontal of vertical, but an issue I saw was that when the BoxLayout was set to vertical, the toggle of each item was mute, you had to go one by one from the bottom-up. This was weird. You can click on each AccordionItem, where the RstDocument is not. This should be a great starting point. Noticed this effect doesn't occur when using a Label, so that could be a another option.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.rst import RstDocument
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class ShowrstApp (App):

    def update_size(self, instance, *args):
        instance.height = 100 * len(instance.children) # set Accordion height to the number of accordionItem times the height accordionItem height

    def build (self):
        numitems = 10

        root = BoxLayout()
        accheight = numitems * 60
        accitems = Accordion(id='acc_panel', orientation='vertical', size_hint_y=None, pos_hint={'top':1}
                            height=accheight, md_bg_color=(1, 1, 1, 1))

        for i in xrange(numitems * 2): # *2 to show it works
            item = AccordionItem(title='This is item: %d' % i)
            somecontent = BoxLayout(orientation = 'horizontal') # couldn't solve an issue I notice so I used horizontal
            somecontent.add_widget(RstDocument(text='Some nicely formatted text here' * 10))
            somecontent.add_widget(Button(text='click here', height=(42), size_hint=(1,None)))
            item.add_widget(somecontent)
            accitems.bind(size=self.update_size)
            accitems.add_widget(item)
        sv = ScrollView(do_scroll_x = False)
        sv.add_widget(accitems)

        root.add_widget(sv)
        return root


Window.size = (350,650)
showrst = ShowrstApp()
showrst.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that the combi of a Scrolling RstDocument and a ScrollView does not work together. I got rid of the RstDocument and changed into Label which makes it better. However, still struggling with the sizing of the AccordionItems. I want to have the AccorionItem fixed height but it sounds more easy than Kivy is treating this :(

Comment: The height of AccordionItem is fixed. Do you mean you want to increase the  AccordionItem box where the title goes or the height where the button and label goes?

Comment: The problem about the sizing of the AccordionItem lies here in the bind to self.update_size. In the example above the size of the items themselves is affected as well - and that's not what we want. It seems that Kivy needs an explicit screen update before calculating the needed heigth of the Accordion. So it would be better to make a explicit call through Kivy's Clock and then calculate the needed height.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with RstDocuments in a ScrollView. The problem arises because RstDocuments have their own scrolling and 'intercept' the scroll command because it thinks you're trying to scroll inside the RstDocument. If you're fine with non-scrolling RstDocuments, you can set `do_scroll_y: False` for RstDocument, and scrolling will then work fine in the ScrollView regardless of mousing over an RstDocument.